# Oekobaudat API - Data structure changes and staying informed

Tags: life-cycle-analysis

I'm working on a project to automatically enrich building information models with EPD data using the Oekobaudat API (https://www.oekobaudat.de/en.html). However, I've recently encountered an issue where the API data structure changed without any prior notification.

Since Oekobaudat is maintained by a German general institute, I'm wondering if there's a formal channel to stay informed about such changes, such as a changelog or user mailing list.

Any advice from the community regarding:

Staying informed about future API changes: Are there any official resources (changelogs, mailing lists) provided by Oekobaudat to keep users updated?
Handling unexpected changes: How do others in the community cope with sudden API changes when working with Oekobaudat?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have.

Comment: Did you ask this question to the institute that provides the API?

Comment: I tried the mails given in the documentation but i got informed by an admin of the KIT in Karlsruhe that the mailing list is not active atm